# VBA Filtering more than 2 Criteria

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I'm looking for a simple solution to a filtering issue I have. I'm trying to filter out the following letter combinations in Field 9: *`RB`, `RC` and `RG`*. 
I've tried a few ways of doing this. The first way I tried it was:

```
  Set Bigpic = Workbooks.Open("S:\NFInventory\groups\CID\CID Database\BigPic Files\BigPic 2018.xlsx", , , , , , , , True)
     lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     Rows("1:1").Select
     Selection.AutoFilter
     ActiveSheet.Range("A1:CU" & lrow).AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="<>RB", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>RC", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria3:="<>RG"
```

This failed, so I tried to use an *array* but that also seems to be failing. It returns with just *`RG`* being filtered while the others remain. Any push in the right direction would be helpful.

```
 Set Bigpic = Workbooks.Open("S:\NFInventory\groups\CID\CID Database\BigPic 
 Files\BigPic 2018.xlsx", , , , , , , , True)
     lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     Rows("1:1").Select
     Selection.AutoFilter
     ActiveSheet.Range("A1:CU" & lrow).AutoFilter Field:=9, 
 Criteria1:=Array("<>RB", "<>RC", "<>RG")
```

Comment: You cannot use more than 2 *does not equal*. Build a dictionary or arraylist out of the values that are not equal and use that as the array filter.

Comment: I was afraid of that... Hard way it is then. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use more than 2 *does not equal*. Build a dictionary or arraylist out of the values that are not equal and use that as the array filter with xlfiltervalues.

```
dim i as long, lr as long, arr as object

set arr = createobject("scripting.dictionary")

with ActiveSheet

     lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

     for i=2 to lr
         select case ucase(.cells(i, "I").value2)
             case "RB", "RC", "RG"
                 'do nothing
             case else
                 arr.item(.cells(i, "I").value2) = vbnullstring
         end select
     next i

     .Range("A1:CU" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=9, criteria1:=arr.keys, operator:=xlfiltervalues

end with
```

Answer (score 1):

If is not a problem to have the criteria in a sheet (can be hide)

[image]

In the code you can put the criteria in hide sheet

```
Range("C1:D9").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("G1:I2"), Unique:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

I have manually excluded more than 2 criteria by filtering by color. If your table has no fill defined, this code will work.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:CU" & lrow).AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=Array("RB", _
    "RC", "RG"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:CU" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior.Color = 1 
' 1 is a black fill, change to your preference
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:CU" & lrow).AutoFilter Field:=9, Operator:= _
    xlFilterNoFill
'ActiveSheet.Range("A1:CU" & lrow).Autofilter Field:=9 
'this code will unfilter the range, can be used for testing to confirm everything you  _ 
expected to filter was filtered
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just create a Filter column and put an if statement in it? Something like:

```
=IFERROR(FIND("RB",UPPER(C9)),0)+IFERROR(FIND("RC",UPPER(C9)),0)+IFERROR(FIND("RG",UPPER(C9)),0)
```

and then filter on that column = 0 to exclude all the RB,RC,RGs